# Why can a struct encapsulating a class be a compile-time constant?

Tags: c#

Default parameters must be a compile-time constant so they can be either built-in types or struct. More precisely, they cannot be a class instance.

```
public class Complex { }

public struct Point
{
    public Complex complex;
    public Point(int any)
    {
        complex = new Complex();
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Method1(Point p = new Point()) { }

    //static void Method2(Complex c = new Complex()) { } //cannot be compiled

    static void Main()
    {
        Method1();

        // Method2(); cannot be compiled
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why can a struct encapsulating a class be a compile-time constant recall that a class instance is not a compile-time constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a compile time constant.  Your Point call is allowed as [optional arguemnts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) can be:

- a constant expression;
- an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
- an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

In this case, you're using the 2nd allowed option for optional arguments - an expression of the form `new ValType()`, as a `struct` is a value type.

The fact that your value type encapsulates a class doesn't matter - you get the default value for the value type (which will have `complex` set to `null`).

Comment: Of course I understand these list, what I don't understand is why a class field in a struct can make the struct a compile-time constant.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 because you are using the default parameterless constructor of your struct, and that sets all fields to default values. you can't change the implementation of parameterless constructor, so that's make it compile-time constant

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 It's not a compile time constant.  There are other options which are allowed there.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 The default value of a struct is an allowed optional argument.